# A circular vibrating membrane

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation, linear-pde

Our Lecturer gaves us the following problem:

$u_{tt}=u_{rr}+\frac{u_r}{r}$   ,   $0<r<a,0<t$     (1)

with Initial Conditions (IC):  $u(r,0)=f(r)$, $u_t(r,0)=0$

and Bounadry Conditions (BC): $u(a,t)=0$

The above equations are in polar coordinates and come when someone examines the phainomenon of a vibrating drum. Actually the real equation (instead of (1)) is: $u_{tt}=u_{rr}+\frac{u_r}{r}+\frac{u_{φφ}}{r^2}$  (2)

One of my collegues said that from these IC and BC and equation (1) we can deduce that the problem given is axessymmetric, i.e it does not depend on the angle $φ$... 
So I have tried to prove his words writing:
From (1) and (2) we have: $u_{φφ}=0$
or

$u(r,φ,t)=F(r,t)φ+G(r,t)$

but I could  not get anything significant step using the IC and BC...

**Is my Collegue right?**

Please take in mind that I do not need the solution of the problem of the membrane, I just want to know if it is axissymmetric or not. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the solution is axially symmetric. What you essentially need to show is under given IC and BC, the solution to the PDE is unique.

Let $u_1(r,\phi,t)$ be a solution of PDE under given IC and BC. Since IC and BC is invariant under rotation, for any constant $K$, the function $u_2(r,\phi,t) \stackrel{def}{=} u_1(r,\phi+K,t)$  is also a solution of the problem satisfying same IC and BC.

Let $v = u_1 - u_2$. By construction, it satisfies

$$\begin{array}{rcll}
\text{PDE} &:& v_{tt} = \nabla \cdot (\nabla v)\\
\text{IC}  &:& v(r,\phi,0) = v_t(r,\phi,0) = 0,& \forall r \le a, \forall \phi\\
\text{BC} &:& v(a,\phi,t) = 0,& \forall r \ge 0, \forall \phi
\end{array}$$

Consider following $t$-dependent integral,

$$Q(t) = \int_{B(0,a)} (v_t^2 + |\nabla v|^2) dxdy$$
It is clear $Q(0) = 0$. With help of a 2-d version of divergence theorem, we find
$$\begin{align}
Q'(t) 
&= 2 \int_{B(0,a)} (v_t v_{tt} + (\nabla v_t)\cdot (\nabla v)) dxdy\\
&= 2 \int_{B(0,a)} (v_t \nabla \cdot (\nabla v) +(\nabla v_t)\cdot (\nabla v)) dxdy\\
&= 2 \int_{B(0,a)} \nabla \cdot ( v_t \nabla v) dxdy\\
&= 2 \int_{r = a}  (v_t \nabla v) \cdot \hat{r} ad\phi
\end{align}$$
Since $v_t = 0$ at $r = a$, last integral evaluates to $0$.

This means $Q'(t) = 0$ for $t \ge 0$. This in turn implies $Q(t) = Q(0) = 0$ for $t \ge 0$.

As a result, $v = 0$ and hence $u_2 = u_1$ for $t \ge 0$.

Since this is true for all $K$, the solution $u_1$ of PDE is axially symmetric.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, just one thing I have trouble with: Normally, angle $φ$ takes values between $0$ and $2 π$ so $K$ in the function $u_1$ should take values between $0$ and $2 π$ and most important $φ$ in function $u_2$ should then take values between $0$ and $2π - K$. Can we then say again that solution in the minisque$0<r<α$, $0<φ<2 π$ is unique? I think we can if we use the line integral on the borders of the minisque instead of the circle you mentioned....

Comment: @dmtri Nope, $u_1$ and $u_2$ are solutions defined over $B(0,a) \times [0,\infty)$. The $(r,\phi)$ is just a parametersation of the underlying disk $B(0,a)$ which happens to have some unnatural boundary along the $\phi$ direction. The operation $\phi \mapsto \phi + K$ is really a short hand for rotating the solutions from $u_1$ to $u_2$.